# Running a single feature file before and after a test run

Tags: karate

Was looking for a solution to run a feature file at the end of the suite
My workflow (In parallel Run)

1. karate.callSingle('Login.feature') so at the beginning i do one
   login and then use the cookies/token for the whole suite
2. Run tests in Parallel
3. Runs the Logout.feature file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no direct support for this currently. By the way no one has ever requested this. If this is so important, kindly open a feature request.

One workaround is to set a singleton / Java static variable from `callSingle` and then in your JUnit / Java parallel runner, call the feature to logout using the Java API (search the docs for this) and you can pass arguments / access the static variable.

EDIT: just realized that the [`@AfterClass`](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/AfterClass.html) JUnit annotation may be more than sufficient for your needs.